# Getting error in Java, Have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and I was trying to do the following on eclipse:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hello_World {
  public class HelloWorld extends JFrame
  {  
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame frame = new HelloWorld();
     frame.setSize( 300, 200 );
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     frame.setTitle( "Hello world" );
     frame.setVisible( true );
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what I doing wrong here.
The compiler gives me following error:

```
Main method not found in class Hello_World, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `Hello_World` class does not have a `main` method.

Comment: Your `main` is inside a class, inside another class. it's not visible to the most exteriour class, `Hello_World`.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {` is that the main method?

Comment: Can someone show me how to do this the right way?

Comment: why do you need a static inner class btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you have defined your `main` method inside a nested class, instead of directly in the class that you are compiling.

Just move the `main` method into the `HelloWorld` class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Hello_World {
    public static class HelloWorld extends JFrame
    {  

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new HelloWorld();
        frame.setSize( 300, 200 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setTitle( "Hello world" );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3552670, Please mark this as the accepted answer if it works for you, after the timer finishes.

Comment: Merlin sure :D. `public static class Vb0201 extends JFrame` does that have to be static?

Comment: @user3552670, An inner class has to be `static` if you are trying to create an instance of it outside of an instance of its enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution:

```java
package hello_world;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Hello_World extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Hello_World();
        frame.setSize( 300, 200 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setTitle( "Hello world" );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```